# Internal error 500 by Jersey without any log messages

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I have very weird issue related to the Jersey that didn't happen before. 
I have several POST, PUT or DELETE REST services that stopped working correctly after 2-3 days of the web server start. GET services work properly.

They constantly return 500 error but the service operation completes successfully(inserting or deleting data). There are no error messages or exceptions in the log. I surrounded these services with try/catch blocks but they finish successfully. Issue occurs somewhere after the service method execution.

I added global exception mapper but it also didn't log anything. They most weird thing is that issue disappears after server restart so I cannot catch it.

jersey 2.22.1

Comment: Try [tracing](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/monitoring_tracing.html#tracing)

Comment: If someone is interested I figured out the root cause of the issue. Jersey worked properly. However the response header exceeded maximum size(8192 bytes) due to error in the code. So web server alerted and threw the exception(returned error 500). Since no logging was made in that case it was almost impossible to investigate that.